# Opening a file and selecting specific column in file

Tags: python

Hello all I am new to python and really need help

I have a set of data as below
all large values are column 1 and xx.x are column 2
19600110    28.6
19600111    28.9
19600112    29.2
19600113    28.6
19600114    28.6
19600115    28.4
19600116    28.6
19600117    28.6

stored as station.txt

I am trying to get python to only present the first column of data (19600115 etc) which is labelled dates.I opened the file and I am using a for loop to try only open 1st column. I am not sure where I am going wrong any help would be greatly appreciated

def load_dates(stations):
    """loads station dates and excludes station temperature data"""

```
f = open(stations[0] + '.txt', 'r')
#create a for loop and open first column of data which are the dates
#close the file and return body of dates
dates = []
for line in f:
    dates.append(lines(7))
f.close()

return dates
```

Comment: Each line is "19600110 28.6", you should split it.dates=[line.split()[0] for line in f]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dates = []
for line in f:
    dataItem = line.split() #split by while space by default, as a list
    date = dataItem[0] #index 0 is the first element of the dataItem list
    dates.append(date)
f.close()
```

in summary, you need to split the line string first, then choose the date